Is there a way to bookmark a helpful post?
Is there any way that I can bookmark or flag a post as being helpful or useful so that I can find them again? It would be useful to me if I could have a way to find some of the things I am reading again, to review them.

You can click on the star icon  that is beside the question, underneath the voting controls. Then you will find by clicking the "Activity" tab on your user profile, at the section "Favorites".

THANK YOU!!! ;-)
